# как получить из строки только цифры и точку между числами

Tags: javascript

как получить из строки только цифры и точку между числами например - Код 22.50 - результат должен быть 22.50, это текст записываеться в textarea как можно чтобы когда получались только числа и после каждый код был с абзаца

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnCopy", function() {
        var selectCont = document.querySelector('#codesList'),
            liActive = selectCont.querySelectorAll('li'),
            index = 0,
            copyField = document.getElementById('copyCode'),
            arr = [];
        copyField.innerHTML = "";
        for(index; index < liActive.length; index++) {
            var name = liActive[index].querySelector('.list-name'),
                text = name.textContent,
                template = text + " ";
            arr.push(template);
        }
        copyField.style.display = 'block';
        for (var n = 0; n < arr.length; n++) {
            copyField.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', arr[n]);
        }
        $("#copyCode").focus().select();
        var x = $("#copyCode").focus().select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
str = "код 37.49";
re = /[0-9/.]+/

found = str.match(re)
console.log(found)
```

Answer (score 1):

С помощью регулярки `/\d+\.\d+/.exec('Код 22.50')`